# css - way to not have width assume 100%?

Tags: css, html, css-float, anchor

So when you put a `<div>` within a `<div>`, it assumes it should be all the way wide.

I have an `<a>` element, and the only way to get it to display correctly is to give it `display: block`. However, giving it this attribute makes it behave like the `<div>` does by default. It makes it all the way wide.

I don't have a specific width I want it (just so the text and padding fit) but I don't want it to be all the way wide.

Is there an attribute/workaround for this?

I would post some code but it's a simple enough idea - just say so if you'd like to see some code.

Comment: Please show some code, your question is also kind of ambiguous.

Comment: "and the only way to get it to display correctly" - you need to elaborate on this. what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `display: inline-block;`, but there are only a few times when that is really necessary.

Post some code so we can tell what is causing your anchors to disappear or do whatever undesirable behavior it is.

Oh, it would be helpful to know what you want them to look like.

Comment: I'm sure inline-block is what he wants -- +1.If anyone still cares about IE6, then make sure the element is inline by default. <div>s won't work with inline block in IE6, but if you use a <span> instead it will.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `display: inline`.

If you really need `display: block`, you can make it "shrink-wrap" by setting `float: left`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
display:inline
```

Answer (score 0):

You can float it:

```
div { overflow:auto; }
a { float:left; }


<div>
    <a> Link </a>
</div>
```